# MySQL is not found anywhere on computer

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal, server, localhost

I have recently installed MySQL directly from the website (mysql-5.7.9-osx10.10-x86_64.dmg) and I have run into a great deal of difficulty that started with trying to change the given password.  The error that was returned  was:

> [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be
>   insecure. mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed error:
>   Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock
>   (2)' Check that mysqld is running and that the socket:
>   '/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!

From here I attempted to find the "usr" folder (hidden files are showing) or even anything that closely resembles MySQL anywhere on my computer and got nothing except for installation .dmg files.

I know that MySQL was installed because it is now able to be started and stopped in the System Preferences pane, but clearly none of my commands are working and I keep getting this error no matter what I do:

```
mysql: command not found
```

Can someone give me some clue as to what I am missing?  I've become fairly desperate and can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  I am running El Capitan.

Comment: You need to update your `PATH` environment variable to contain the folder where `mysql` was installed.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I am somewhat of a beginner to this

Answer (score 14):

Well, if you're saying that MySQL is running, you can try looking for it via terminal command like this:

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

which should give something like

```
12345 ... 5 Apr16 9:09.32 /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.17/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.17 --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --bind-address=127.0.0.1
```

so basedir and datadir is probably the most valuable outputs here (please note that your path most likely will be different).

On top of it, in order to get `mysql` command running through terminal you have two options

1. Create simulink from mysql's basedir into your /usr/local/bin directory

   `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.17/bin/mysql /usr/local/bin/mysql`
2. Add mysql's basedir/bin to your path (need to add this to your ~/.bashrc to make it persistent)

   `export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.17/bin/:$PATH`

   New terminal tab is required for these changes to catch up.

Cheers.