# Unable to execute mysql commands from terminal

Tags: mysql, bash, backup

I have just completed a new mySQL install on my Mac. The new install appears to be working properly. I can turn SQL on and off. I can create a database and make tables. I want to restore a database from a dumpfile. When I run the command:

```
mysql -u root -p  BIO < /Volumes/Seagate/sql_bkp.sql
```

I get the error message:

```
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

I have tried running the restore command from my home directory and I get the error message. I also checked to find out where mySQL was installed and did a cd to that directory but I still get the same error. I believe this is some sort of PATH error but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36610619/mysql-is-not-found-anywhere-on-computer) May it could help you. I think is the same pro

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I have already tried the suggestion in this post but had no success. I do believe that the post is pointing in the right direction but I am unable to get the simulink to function. However the answer is a bit vague about the path name to use. Would you know how to establish a simulink?

Answer (score 0):

run this command

```
$ ps -ax|grep mysql
```

in the output you can see the path

```
18470 s001  S      0:00.02 /bin/sh /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.15/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --pid-file=/usr/loca.....
```

Then you can set the PATH or start with absolute PATH like:

```
$ /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.15/bin/mysql -u root -p  BIO < /Volumes/Seagate/sql_bkp.sql
```

Comment: This is getting closer but still no success. The ps -ax|grep mysql command gives:  0:00.03 /bin/sh /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir . So I tried this at the command prompt: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe -u root -p 'my password'  < /Volumes/Seagate/sql_bkp.sql and I got a long message with a bunch of permission denied statements. Here is a portion of the error message: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 586: /usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld_safe.pid: Permission denied
awk: i/o error occurred while closing /dev/stdout
 input record number 2, file 
 source line number 1

Comment: @Bill Orton  - great - then start this **/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p  BIO < /Volumes/Seagate/sql_bkp.sql** . it will be run

Comment: read my message again. not start mysqld_safe !!! start mysql . Here the commandline again: **$ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p BIO < /Volumes/Seagate/sql_bkp.sql**. i start the ps only to see in which location the other mysql commands are stored

Comment: If I run  /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p BIO < /Volumes/Seagate/sql_bkp.sql at the terminal prompt all that happens is I get what appears to be the help comments for Usage: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql [OPTIONS] [database]. The backup does not seem to restore.

Comment: start only this : **/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p** and after you gives the password type the command **SHOW DATABASES;** to see if there one. you can exit with the quit command

Comment: you can also install **sequel pro** it a graphical MySQL gui. there you can also create databases and also import SQL files, edit data and many more.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. When I execute the command you just outlined I get the same help comments as before. No databases are shown. I'm sure the database exists because I can access it with inserts and updates no problem I just can't get the backup to restore.

Comment: do you have teamviewer or want to call me. then we can fix the problem and add the result after this

Comment: Hi, I don't have teamviewer but I would gladly call you. Before we try that... I just successfully installed sequel pro and connected to my DB with no problem. Is it possible to use sequel pro to restore a database?

Comment: ok, but teamviewer is also free and the we can do the work together.

Comment: Hooray!! The sequel pro import command successfully restored my database. Thank you very much for your help. Also thank you for pointing out sequel pro to me, that was very helpful. Have a great day and thanks again!!